# Find the total resistance of circuit with both series and parallel resistors

Tags: resistors, parallel, series

I found this circuit in a textbook, but I'm having a difficult time calculating the total resistance here. I tried using the formula for parallel resistors with the 3 resistors the the upper left, and then add that to the most right resistors. This would give me the total resistance of the upper half of the circuit. I then used that resistance, and used the formula for parallel circuits with the lower portion, but that gave me an incorrect answer.

The solution is supposedly 10ohm / 11.

[image]

Comment: This is recognizable as an application of a delta /wye transformation

Comment: @placeholder it can be done still simpler by series/parallel transformations. R is 1 ohm.

Comment: @RogerC. you're no fun ... ;)

Comment: @placeholder ok, I got it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If R=1, your approach is correct.

1. 1 // 2 = <sup>2</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub>
2. <sup>2</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub> + 1 = <sup>5</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub>
3. <sup>5</sup>⁄<sub>3</sub> // 2 = <sup>10</sup>⁄<sub>11</sub>

1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEjbpi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuQYTA.png)</sup>